# Why data types are conflicting?

Tags: c, function, types

I am using code blocks with gcc compiler when I encountered this problem ...
error: conflicting types for func32();
I tried changing name of the function. but still don't work

```
static void func32(int, int);

void main()
{
    int a = 4, b = 5, c = 6;
    func31(a, b);
    func32(&b, &c);
    printf("The Result Will Be: %d\n", c - a - b);
}

static void func32(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c;
    c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: Just do simple spot the difference: `static void func32(int, int);` vs `static void func32(int *a, int *b)`

Comment: "I tried changing name of the function. but still don't work" I don't understand why you expect this to help. Did the error message say "conflicting names for function"? No; it said "conflicting *types* for function". Therefore....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `func32` says that it takes two integers (`int`).

```
static void func32(int, int);
```

On the other hands, your definition of `func32` says that it takes two pointers (`int*`).

```
static void func32(int *a, int *b)
```

Here is the confrict. The declaration and definition should use the same signature. In this case the arguments should be pointers.

Comment: Questions like OP's are not supposed to be answered, as they boil down to either a typographical error or a misunderstanding of language fundamentals, neither of which are considered appropriate.

Comment: the new declaration statement: static void func32(int *a, int *b);

Answer (score 0):

```
static void func32(int, int);
```

memory locations are not always in integer type. the signature in definition and the value passed to it are very different in their data types. hence a conflict.

```
static void func32(int *a, int *b)
```

explanation

```
int a = 1:
int *p = &a; /* stores some number or sometimes alphanumeric address. you will come to notice when you simply print p
dereference it and you get a. printf("%d",*p);   */
```